# Data Source instance in the list grid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am using smart gwt 2.2 on windows system in mozilla browser.
I am using List Grid instance in my application.
In that list grid instance I am filling data using data source.
Method for set data:

// Entry point method

```
  public void init() {
   final ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
   DataSource ds= new DataSource();
   ds.setClientOnly(true);
   setDataSourceField(ds);
   ds.setTestData(getGridData());
   grid.setFields(getGridFields());
   grid.setDataSource(ds);
   setGridProperty(grid);
   grid.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
     DataSource ds= new DataSource();
     ds.setClientOnly(true);
     setDataSourceField(ds);
     ds.setTestData(getGridData());
     grid.setFields(getGridFields());
     grid.setDataSource(ds);
     grid.draw();
    }
   });
   myCanvas.addChild(grid);
  }
```

//dummy data

```
 private static ListGridRecord[] getGridData() {
   ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
   record.setAttribute("id", "1");
   record.setAttribute("name", "11");
   record.setAttribute("address", "111");
   ListGridRecord record1 = new ListGridRecord();
   record1.setAttribute("id", "2");
   record1.setAttribute("name", "222");
   record1.setAttribute("address", "222");

   return new ListGridRecord[] { record, record1 };
  }

//grid property
  private static void setGridProperty(ListGrid grid) {
   grid.setWidth("90%");
   grid.setHeight(125);
   grid.setAutoFetchData(true);
  }

//fields
  private static ListGridField[] getGridFields() {
   ListGridField field = new ListGridField("id");
   ListGridField field1 = new ListGridField("name");
   ListGridField field2 = new ListGridField("address");
   return new ListGridField[] { field, field1 ,field2};
  }

//data source field
  protected static void setDataSourceField(DataSource dataSource) {
   DataSourceField idField = new DataSourceField("id", FieldType.TEXT);
   idField.setPrimaryKey(true);
   DataSourceField nameField = new DataSourceField("name",
     FieldType.TEXT);
   DataSourceField addField = new DataSourceField("address", FieldType.TEXT);
   dataSource.setFields(nameField, idField, addField);
  }
```

On click of the row of the grid I want to add a new data source instance to the grid, but it is not showing any data.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `grid.fetchData()` method and bind datasource one more time to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try **grid.invalidateCache()**